# ubuntu terminal is stuck at -bash-5.5$

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I was trying to switch to wsl2. so based on some websites instruction I used ctrl+alt+T and my terminal changed to '-bash-5.5$'. I guess I'm in the root directory and I can't get out for some reason. I have tried "exit"command, 'ctrl+c','ctrl+s','ctrl+d'

Comment: What do you mean by "get out"?  Are you trying to exit wsl? Do you just want to change your ps1 prompt? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I want my shell to go back to normal. the previous format was ala@acerlaptop.
That's how my command lines used to look like.

Comment: "some websites instructions"? Ask them.